# preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class

Tags: php, regex

```
if ( preg_match('/['.$i_word.']*( )*['.$p_word.']*/', $string, $match) ){
echo "<br>";
echo "more positive comment";
```

i am getting the same error. Here i am tying to match the two variables whether the matches my string or not. But getting the error: **Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 16**

Comment: What are the contents of `$i_word` and `$p_word`? Are you sure they don't have any special regex characters in them? Try `var_dump('/['.$i_word.']*( )*['.$p_word.']*/');` before the if and edit the results into your queation.

Comment: the contents are string and it doesn't contain any special regex.

Comment: then I can't imagine why that would happen. Just for fun, a link to a useful function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: In addition to @Terminus's comment (please post your variables here), why do you capture whitespaces unlimited times?

Comment: i had same problem, i have used suggestion of Terminus and so var_dumped regex and have found that the included string was empty string, so i have "[]" in regex. --- its cause was that i used global variable in function, but defined it just before "function", but after that function was called.

Answer (score 0):

Either `$i_word` or `$p_word` contains `[` or ends with `\` and this makes the first argument of [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) an invalid regex.

Use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) with `$i_word` and `$p_word` to produce correct regex fragments from them:

```
$regex = '/['.preg_quote($i_word, '/').']*( )*['.preg_quote($p_word, '/').']*/';
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    // success
}
```